# How to translate strings by format on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, translation, rails-i18n

I'm getting some string into my database from an external API and I want to translate them before showing users. I don't want to translate each object by globalize3 because content that I want to translate has some format.

For example I need to change all information values with date:

"Game postponed from 22.08.2013" -> date changes but string is same.

I tried using string as key and it works if I dont have variable:

config/locale/tr.yml file

> tr:
>
> Hello World: "Merhaba Dunya"

rails console

> I18n.t("Hello World")
>
> => "Merhaba Dunya"

How can i use my string with variable as key and get translated one?

I want to define this:

> tr:
>
> "Game postponed from %{date}" => "Mac %{date} tarihinden ertelendi"

and I want to use it by:

> I18n.t("Game postponed from 22.08.2013")
>
> => "Mac 22.08.2013 tarihinden ertelendi"

Using I18n may not be best solution to my case but I don't know how can I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/locale/tr.yml`

```
'Game postponed from': 'Game postponed from %{date}'
```

Console:

```
I18n.t 'Game postponed from', :date => some_date
```

Comment: I know how to pass variable to I18n but my problem is I don't have a variable. "Game postponed from 22.08.2013" is a string that saved in my database.

Comment: Split the string into two parts, lookup 'Game postponed from' using I18n, and then use the date string as the variable

Comment: @Slicedpan I'm looking for a general solution to this case. I've tons of different format "Game postponed ..." is just an example. I might need to localize "%{name} scored first goal" and "Game referee is %{name}". If I split them programatically I can also swap them because my site only has one language.

Comment: Is there any way in general to tell which part of each string is translatable?

Comment: @Slicedpan no :( I try to create an admin panel to add formats(like "Game postponed from %{date}") and their values but I still don't know how I match them with database fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version with an example:

```rb
> I18n.transliterate("arrêter".downcase.strip)
=> "arreter"
```